# How to change the locales from US to japan in react-big-calendar?

Tags: typescript, next.js, react-big-calendar

Currently I'm working on calendar component using react-big-calendar library and my objective is to change the localization to japan but it won't change

error:
Unexpected require().
'ja' is defined but never used.

code:

```
import { Calendar, dateFnsLocalizer } from 'react-big-calendar';
import format from 'date-fns/format';
import ja from 'date-fns/locale/ja';
import parse from 'date-fns/parse';
import startOfWeek from 'date-fns/startOfWeek';
import getDay from 'date-fns/getDay';
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css';

const locales = {
  ja: require('date-fns/locale/ja'),
};
const localizer = dateFnsLocalizer({
  format,
  parse,
  startOfWeek,
  getDay,
  locales,
});

export const MyCalendar = () => (
  <div>
    <Calendar localizer={localizer} style={{ height: '80vh' }} />
  </div>
);
```

I changed the import from
`import ja from 'date-fns/locale/ja';`

to
`import { ja } from 'date-fns/locale/ja';`

but it doesn't work so help me to change japanese

Comment: Please read errors, don't ignore them. You `import ja from 'date-fns/locale/ja';` but never use the variable, because you import it again here: `ja: require('date-fns/locale/ja'),`

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't change the date formatting itself, or even the language it displays things in. You accomplish this by doing what you've already done, along with adjusting the various `formats` props, supplying a valid `culture` prop, and adjusting the `messages` prop. See the Big Calendar documentation for greater detail. Their Localization Example gives the entire big picture on how to accomplish this.